# How to find a text between two characters and replace it by a text between another two characters of a line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have many lines of bibliography as the following:

```
@article{mehri_buckling_2016, title = {Buckling }, doi = {10.1016/j.cma.2016.01.017}}

@article{jin_modified_2014, title = {A modified ns}, doi = {10.1016/j.apacoust.2014.04.007}}

@article{sofiyev_free_2017, title = {The free}, doi = {10.1016/j.compositesb.2017.03.054}}

@article{malekzadeh_three-dimensional_2012, title = {Three-dimensional free }}

@article{jooybar_thermal_2016, title = {Thermal panels}, doi = {10.1016/j.tws.2016.01.032}}
```

In each line may there is `doi={...}` or not. 
I need to replace the words between `@article{......`, by the word between `doi = {...}`, if there is doi in its line.

For this example results should become:

```
@article{10.1016/j.cma.2016.01.017, title = {Buckling }, doi = {10.1016/j.cma.2016.01.017}}

@article{10.1016/j.apacoust.2014.04.007, title = {A modified ns}, doi = {10.1016/j.apacoust.2014.04.007}}

@article{10.1016/j.compositesb.2017.03.054, title = {The free}, doi = {10.1016/j.compositesb.2017.03.054}}

@article{malekzadeh_three-dimensional_2012, title = {Three-dimensional free }}

@article{10.1016/j.tws.2016.01.032, title = {Thermal panels}, doi = {10.1016/j.tws.2016.01.032}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

- Find what: `^(@article\{).*?(,.*?doi = \{)(.*?)\}`
- Replace with: `\1\3\2\3}`
- Regular expression: **checked**
- `.` matches newline: **cleared**

Explanation:

- `^` is maybe optional, but it ensures that the match can only occur at the beginning of a line.
- `(@article\{)` matches literally `@article{`. The brace had to be escaped with a backslash, as it is a special character in regexes. The parentheses make it possible to refer to this string with `\1` later. It's a so called "capture group"
- `.*?` will match any series of characters , but not more than necessary to get a complete match ("lazy"): `.` means any character, `*` any number of them, `?` but as few as possible to make the rest work.
- `(,.*?doi = \{)` matches a literal comma, then again some more characters (see previous point), followed by a literal `doi = {`. The parentheses make it possible to refer to this as `\2` later.
- `(.*?)` matches a number of characters (see above). The parentheses make it possible to refer to this as `\3` later. This is the part that matches the actual text that needs to be copied.
- `\}` a literal `}`.

The replacement uses the capture groups:

- `\1` is synonymous for `@article{`
- `\3` is the text that needs to be copied
- `\2` is whatever appeared between `,` and `doi = {`, including those two texts.
- `\3` is repeated to just restore the `doi` value as it was.
- `}` is the closing brace that was matched at the end of the "find" pattern. We want to keep it as well of course.

Comment: Added explanation.