# Replace by Swapping Text on Each Side of '=' Using Notepad++ Find/Replace

Tags: notepad++

After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59490439/12041806), I was curious about trying to solve a problem I had in the past.

Say I have a file which looks like the following:

```
self.theta = theta
self.alpha = alpha
self.beta = beta
```

I want to be able to swap the text on each side of the equals sign, turning it into:

```
theta = self.theta
alpha = self.alpha
beta = self.beta
```

I was able to solve this by using [Vim like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374154/12041806), but I would like to know how to do this directly in Notepad++. I am not asking how to swap text around an equal sign, I am looking for the correct way to do so using the built-in Find/Replace functionality in Notepad++.

From [the answer referenced at the beginning of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59490439/12041806), I tried to use the following Find/Replace:

- Find what: `(.*?)=(.*?)`
- Replace with: `\2 = \1`
- Wrap around: **checked**
- Regular expression: **checked**
- `.` matches newline: **cleared**

This however produces the output:

```
 = self.theta  theta
 = self.alpha  alpha
 = self.beta  beta
```

What is the correct way to use regular expressions and pattern matching in Notepad++ to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current regex pattern is that it doesn't have `^` and `$` anchors, and therefore the matching behavior is not what you expect, [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/UaYjOW/3).  Since you have DOT ALL mode turned off, the first `(.*?)` is matching everything up the `=`, while the second `(.*)` is matching nothing.  This leaves the RHS term alone during the replacement, leading to the output you see now.  I would suggest the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^(.*)\s*=\s*(.*)$
Replace: $2 = $1
```

### Demo